# yield if content, render something otherwise (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rendering

I've been away from Rails for a while now, so maybe I'm missing something simple.

How can you accomplish this:

```
<%= yield_or :sidebar do %>
  some default content
<% end %>
```

Or even:

```
<%= yield_or_render :sidebar, 'path/to/default/sidebar' %>
```

In the first case, I'm trying:

```
def yield_or(content, &block)
  content_for?(content) ? yield(content) : yield
end
```

But that throws a 'no block given' error.

In the second case:

```
def yield_or_render(content, template)
  content_for?(content) ? yield(content) : render(template)
end
```

This works when there's no content defined, but as soon as I use content_for to override the default content, it throws the same error.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611278/rails-3-yield-return-or-callback-wont-call-in-view-yieldsidebar-rend) as a starting point, but it seems it only works when used directly in the view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

How about something like this?

```
<% if content_for?(:whatever) %>
  <div><%= yield(:whatever) %></div>
<% else %>
  <div>default_content_here</div>
<% end %>
```

[Inspiration from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193838/rails-check-if-yield-area-is-defined-in-content-for)

Comment: It seems that will be  that I use this pattern a lot, so I wanted to extract it into a helper.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def yield_or(name, content = nil, &block)
  if content_for?(name)
    content_for(name)
  else
    block_given? ? capture(&block) : content
   end
end
```

so you could do

```
<%= yield_or :something, 'default content' %>
```

or

```
<%= yield_or :something do %>
    block of default content
<% end %>
```

where the default can be overridden using

```
<%= content_for :something do %>
    overriding content
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've also asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7409646/305668) to see if I can make this more succinct.

Comment: `yield_or`, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you could use `content_for(:content_tag)` without a block and it will return the same content as if using `yield(:content_tag)`.

So:

```
def yield_or_render(content, template)
  content_for?(content) ? content_for(content) : render(template)
end
```