# Yielding content_for with a block of default content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Our Rails projects make heavy use of `content_for`. However, we quite often need to render default content if nothing is defined using `content_for`. For readability and maintainability it makes sense for this default content to be in a block.

We made a helper method in Rails 2.3 and we've now refactored this for Rails 3 (as below).

Both those helpers work very well but I'm wondering if there's a more succinct way I could achieve the same thing in Rails 3.

### Rails 2.3:

```
def yield_or(name, content = nil, &block)
  ivar = "@content_for_#{name}"

  if instance_variable_defined?(ivar)
    content = instance_variable_get(ivar)
  else
    content = block_given? ? capture(&block) : content
  end

  block_given? ? concat(content) : content
end
```

which is useful for doing things like this:

```
<%= content_for :sidebar_content do %>
    <p>Content for the sidebar</p>
<% end %>

<%= yield_or :sidebar_content do %>
    <p>Default content to render if content_for(:sidebar_content) isn't specified</p>
<% end %>
```

### Refactored for Rails 3:

```
def yield_or(name, content = nil, &block)
  if content_for?(name)
    content_for(name)
  else
    block_given? ? capture(&block) : content
  end
end
```

Comment: Lovely little helper ("Refactored for Rails 3")

Answer (score 3):

This can be done entirely in the view using the content_for? method.

```
<% if content_for?(:sidebar_content) %>
  <%= yield(:sidebar_content) %>
<% else %>
  <ul id="sidebar">
    <li>Some default content</li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It can indeed, as shown in "Refactored for Rails 3" above. However, I really like not having to do branching in views if I can avoid it which is why I wrote the yield_or helper. Just a matter of opinion really. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure what it is you're asking, then.